# grep -o search stop at first instance of second expression, rather then last? Greedy?

Tags: grep

Not sure who to phrase this question

This is an example line.

```
30/Oct/2019:00:17:22 +0000|v1|177.95.140.78|www.somewebsite.com|200|162512|-|-|0.000|GET /product/short-velvet-cloak-with-hood/?attribute_pa_color=dark-blue&attribute_pa_accent-color=gold&attribute_pa_size=small  HTTP/1.0|0|0|-
```

I need to extract `attribute_pa_color=`

So I have

```
cat somewebsite.access.log.2.csv | grep -o "?.*=" > just-parameters.txt
```

Which works but if there are multiple parameters in the URL is returns all of them

So instead of stopping the match at the first instance of "=" its taking the last instance of "=" in the line.

How can I make it stop at the first.

I tried this

```
cat somewebsite.access.log.2.csv | grep -o "?(.*?)=" > just-parameters2.txt

cat somewebsite.access.log.2.csv | grep -o "\?(.*?)=" > just-parameters2.txt
```

Both return nothing

Also I need each unique parameter so once I created the file I ran

```
sort just-parameters.txt | uniq > clean.txt
```

Which does not appear to work, is it possible to remove duplicates and have it be part of them same command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like with `awk`

```
awk -F'[?&]' '{print $2}' somewebsite.access.log.2.csv|sort -u > clean.txt
```

This will work if `attribute_pa_color` is the first parameter on URL

If you want to extract only text `attribute_pa_color=` you can try something like:

```
awk -F'[?&]' '{print $2}' somewebsite.access.log.2.csv|awk -F\= '{print $1"="}'|sort -u > clean.txt
```

Instead of using second `awk` you can try something like:

```
awk -F'[?&]' '{split($2,a,=);print a[1]}' somewebsite.access.log.2.csv|sort -u > clean.txt
```

Split internally in `awk` using `=` as delimiter

Comment: This maybe working but it is printing the "HTTP/1.0|0|0|-" and also it is printing the the first parameter and its value, which maybe is because I did not out line my issue clearly [code]attribute_pa_color=dark-green-with-black
attribute_pa_color=dark-green-with-bordeaux
attribute_pa_color=dark-grey
attribute_pa_color=dark-grey HTTP/1.0|0|0|-
attribute_pa_color=dark-grey HTTP/1.0|1|0|-
attribute_pa_color=dark-red[/code] What I need is just attribute_pa_color

Comment: SO you need to extract only string `attribute_pa_color=`? About other text please check again, it work fine for me